# Any alternative to Sybase Sql Advantage?

Tags: editor, sybase

Sybase Sql Advantage is the default editor for the Sybase database. But it has lots of shortcomings, because it basically is what Notepad is for Windows users:

- Can't do multiple undo's
- Monochrome, text is black and background is white
- Can't see what character did you exactly paste from clipboard, and sometimes this lead to weirdness behaviour
- Don't see what line or column you are in the moment
- Lack of funcionality like exports to different formats, integration with source control, plugins, etc.

I have to deal with this editor in my daily work, so I was wondering if there are any other tool. Do you know any replacement?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743286/sybase-development-ide/

Answer (score 4):

There is [TOAD](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-data-analysts/) and [AQUA](http://www.aquafold.com/sybasesqlsybasedatabase.html) but neither is free although demos allow you try before you buy. I use [ASEISQL](http://code.google.com/p/aseisql/) which is free and does a lot of what you're after very well. I can't imagine going back to sql advantage.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Aqua's Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/) a lot -- and they aren't expensive for personal use. In addition to Sybase, a whole bunch of other database-servers are supported from within the same interface. Written in Java the app really does run anywhere -- I use it on FreeBSD, for example. In fact, FreeBSD even has the [databases/adstudio](http://freshports.org/databases/adstudio) port already.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has syntax highlighting for SQL and can run a command on the file in the editor.  Notepad++ can function as a SQL IDE.

free:  http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

I assume that anyone who has Sybase SQL Advantage also has `isql`.
Mine is under `C:/Sybase/BIN/isql.exe`.

One can use the notepad++ NppExec plugin for calling isql.

[How to install and run](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/b/weblog/archive/2013/08/21/using-notepad-to-execute-oracle-sql.aspx):

1. Launch Notepad++
2. Main menu -> Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager
3. Available Tab, Find and check NppExec plugin
4. Press Install button to download & install plugin – restarts Notepad++
5. Open a SQL script
6. Press F6 key (NppExec’s default execute keyboard mapping)
7. Enter something like:

   `c:/Sybase/BIN/isql -U yourUser -P secret -S yourDB -i$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(FILE_NAME)`

Whereby the path `C:/Sybase/BIN` will need to be your path to your isql executable.  If the path to isql is in your PATH variable, then the path can be excluded:

```
  isql -U yourUser -P secret -S yourDB -i$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(FILE_NAME)
```

8. Either save as a script or press the OK button to run.

If you save the script, then it does save your password in a file; you might not want to do that...
One could leave the password field empty when saving the script and then add the password in before running.  Just don't save the password in your script file, if that is a issue for you (which it should be).

Upon running an external command (isql in this case), Notepad++ show the output in a console window.

Caveat:  Notepad++ may have issues when displaying millions of records.